# Get Parent job's build number in jenkins instead of promoted build number

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job `A` and Promotion job configured in `A`.
I am passing certain parameters in promotion job and build-number of Parent job A is one among them.

If I pass `${BUILD_ID}` in the shell part of promotion job, it takes the promotion job build number.

ie, I have a job `A` - build  #1 and promotion job `B` #2, I am passing `$BUILD_ID` and value `2` is getting passed instead of value `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID of the job being promoted can be obtained using the environment variable - `PROMOTED_ID`. For additional information and other environment variables, please see the [doc](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin)

Comment: Also $PROMOTED_NUMBER does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved using one of the environment variables.
`PROMOTED_ID` did the magic  !!!